# Why does setTimeout not work from the chrome devtools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Very simple test in chrome devtools

```
 setTimeout(alert, 1000)
```

In Chrome devtools, nothing happens (it does return a timerId) but the timer never fires.
In Firefox, this does open an alert box.

Why would setTimeout not work from chrome devtools?

Version 53.0.2785.101 (64-bit) on Mac

Hmmm, found an interesting byproduct, closing devtools causes the code timeout to occur.  So it only happens when devtools is still open.

Comment: It works in Chrome for me

Comment: It works for me also in 53.0.2785.116 (64-bit) Mac. Maybe reset your Chrome if it is still happening.

Comment: I guess you were debugging and js was *paused on a breakpoint*. Since js engine is single-threaded, the event could fire only when execution was resumed after closing devtools. Another method of resuming is pressing F8 key or "play" button" in devtools.

Comment: Wasn't debugging, just picked the mozilla doc page for setTimeout and pasted some code into the dev console.